# Python: Creating Default Argument for Pushbutton Connected Function

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I have a QPushButton connected to trigger a function by:

> self.pbLoad.clicked.connect(self.loadData)

This works great, however I would like to give that function a default argument in case I want to load a file manually in the code (for debugging). I tried:

> ```
> def loadData(self,fileName = None):
>     if fileName is None:
>         fileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Choose data file to open', '.', filter='*.lvm')
>     if fileName:
>         self.filename = fileName
>         self.parseFilename()
> ```

However this breaks my button and it stops working. Similarly, if I connect the button instead as:

> self.pbLoad.clicked.connect(self.loadData())

The button is pressed as soon as the GUI is launched. Any ideas how I can get this to work without declaring an extra wrapper function? Thanks.

Comment: The `clicked` signal has a default parameter which always sends `False` - unless the button is checkable, in which case it sends the checked state. So all you need to do is change the first conditional statement in `loadData` to `if not fileName:` and everything will work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have compatibility between the signal and the slot.

In that case, your signal sends no parameters, your slot must have no parameter.

I'd use a wrapper function as a slot and call the actual real function that you want to test.

About `self.pbLoad.clicked.connect(self.loadData())`

when you try to link the button to the function, you actually CALL the function : in that case, you connect your button with the return valuer of the function, which is None, hence, NOT connecting the button.

I'd use:

```
def __init__(self):
   self.pbLoad.clicked.connect(self.buttonClickedSlot)
def buttonClickedSlot(self):
   self.loadData()
def loadData(self,fileName = None):
   .....
```

Comment: Perfect! Makes sense, so I guess I will have to go with creating a wrapper function then. Thanks for the quick reply. Cheers

Comment: The first part of this answer is wrong: it is not necessary for the signature of the signal and the receiver to match. In pyqt, unused signal parameters are silently discarded. But in any case, the signature of [`clicked`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) *does* almost exactly match the signature of `loadData`. The only difference is that `clicked` is sending `False`, but `loadData` is expecting `None` (but that's easy enough to work around).

Comment: oups, my bad. I mostly did Qt on C++ where you have to match exactly